# Connecting user data from multiple tables and returning that info to the specific user?

Tags: php, mysql

I have quite a bit of code- so much that it'd likely confuse people. So I'll just explain the fundamental core concept of what my issue is.

I have two different MySQL data tables. The first holds the username, password, and email. The second holds whatever the user typed for their classes they were taking next year (Math, Science, etc.).

Whenever the user logs in, I want it to display their username and a list of classes. So far, I've been able to get just the username to appear once they've logged in, but NOT the classes they typed in during the account creation process.

I've tried to minimize the amount of code here for everyone not to get confused. (uidUsers is the username, class1 is the name of their first class they entered, idUsers is the unique auto_incremented ID the user gets once they've entered data.

When "Jacob" signs up, his ID in the first table is 1, and all the classes he typed in which go into the second table, are also associated with the ID of 1).

```
     //Backend Code- this file basically checks if the user exists, if they've entered the wrong password, etc. when logging in

     else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
            $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];            
            $_SESSION['class1'] = $row['class1'];


  //Front End- what the user sees when they've logged in

      if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {                 
                echo '<form        action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
            </form>';
                echo $_SESSION['userUid'];
                echo $_SESSION['class1'];
                exit(); 

            }
```

Comment: Look up the JOIN statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to access multiple tables in a single query.

Comment: You'll have to `JOIN` the two tables on their userID.

Comment: Or without using `JOIN`, why not just `SELECT` all classes related to the user since you already have the user's id?

Comment: Ok so I suppose that joins it once. But it still doesn't solve the issue of returning the data to the user once they've logged in.